# How to use environment variables as #defines in eclipse

Tags: svn, g++, environment-variables, c-preprocessor

I wish to assign a build number as part of my (C++) project's version information.  I'd like either g++ or Eclipse to call some external script that would bump up (or not if I choose to leave it fixed at release time) the BUILD_NUMBER and then pick up BUILD_NUMBER as a #defined value in my code.  Is this possible?  How would I do it?  Please note, I want this value to be more restricted that might be a C++ variable.  It will be a variable till we declare the build to be, say, beta.  Then it'll lock down.

As an alternative, I could use the SVN version number.  It is available to Eclipse to stuff into an environment var or #define-d value?

I have looked around google and in the Eclipse fora and find lots of entries that share the same search words as I would use to ask this question.  Nothing quite on-topic turned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that meets my needs at http://th0nt.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/use-build-variables-in-eclipse-cdt-to-simplify-setting-work/ .  The gist of it is tro add a -D VERSION_NUMBER=`myShellScript` to the Properties->C/C++ Builds->GCC C++ Compiler->Miscellaneous property.  Put myShellScript somewhere on the path.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse invokes your makefile, typically with the 'all' target by default (you can change the targets in Projects > Properties > C++ Build > Behavior > Workbench Build Behavior.)

Since your question doesn't make mention of your makefile, that's probably the key to the problem: you need to add code to your makefile which ensures that the build number header (to be created) is produced before g++ is invoked.

If you're unfamiliar with GNU 'make', you should start with that.   As for getting the current rev from Subversion, you can do this in a bash script or make recipe:

```
echo "#define SVN_REV=$(svn info | grep 'Last Changed Rev:' | cut -c 17 )" > my_version_header.h
```

This command first runs 'svn info', selects the last changed revision line, trims off the start of the line, and writes the result to a C header file.

Comment: Very elegant solution.  However, I tried it before and after an svn commit, with no chnage in the reported version.  PLease see my own response below for another solution I found - after i asked this question, of course.

Comment: How does svn know which project i have open in Eclipse?  More than 1 are listed in the Project Explorer.  Since (I think) this runs in a daughter shell of the one where eclipse is running, does the launcher copy the svn project id forward into the daughter shell?

Comment: Svn doesn't know anything about Eclipse.  When Eclipse invokes your makefile, it does so in the project directory ordinarily (unless you do your build in some sub-node).   If you run 'svn info' in the project directory, svn fetches the current directory to figure out what info to retrieve.    With regard to your eclipse-centric solution described elsewhere, my only objection would be that you're coupling Eclipse to your build process... i.e. you lose the ability to build properly from the command line, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$Revision$ Subversion keyword](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) (and set svn:keywords appropriately) to get the last changed revision for the *file* inserted/updated.

However, if you want the revision number for the whole "project" (directory), you'll need to do as described [here in the FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#version-value-in-source).